# MySql Join Query left join

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have table name **students**  having fields **student_id, house_id**  etc.. 
and subjects, houses, students_subjects

I am using this query

```
SELECT students_subjects.student_id,students.house_id,students_subjects.subject_id,subjects.subject_name,students.rollno,students.first_name, students.last_name FROM 
students_subjects LEFT JOIN students on students_subjects.student_id=students.id
LEFT JOIN subjects on students_subjects.subject_id=subjects.id  WHERE students_subjects.class_years_section_id=1
```

This is working  fine for me ..

Now i want to get house name too from houses table

I tried this query

```
SELECT students_subjects.student_id,students.house_id,houses.house_name, students_subjects.subject_id,subjects.subject_name,students.rollno,students.first_name, students.last_name FROM 
students_subjects LEFT JOIN students on students_subjects.student_id=students.id
LEFT JOIN subjects on students_subjects.subject_id=subjects.id
```

LEFT JOIN houses on students.house_id=houses.id
 WHERE students_subjects.class_years_section_id=1

```
AND students_subjects.school_session_id=1 AND students.is_active=1
```

and it gives me house_name = NULL

Can anybody tell me how to get house name too . using join query

Thanks

Comment: This is common [MySQL knowledge](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html). You cannot put a `JOIN` after a `WHERE` statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error in your query is caused by the `LEFT JOIN` keyword that is after `WHERE` clause,

```
SELECT  students_subjects.student_id,
        students.house_id,
        students_subjects.subject_id,
        subjects.subject_name,
        students.rollno,
        students.first_name, 
        students.last_name 
FROM    students_subjects 
        LEFT JOIN students 
            on students_subjects.student_id=students.id
        LEFT JOIN subjects 
            on students_subjects.subject_id=subjects.id
        LEFT JOIN houses 
            on students.house_id=houses.id
WHERE   students_subjects.class_years_section_id = 1 AND 
        students_subjects.school_session_id = 1 AND 
        students.is_active = 1
```

Remember that `JOIN`s are part of the `FROM` Clause.

---

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT  b.student_id,
        a.house_id,
        b.subject_id,
        c.subject_name,
        a.rollno,
        a.first_name, 
        a.last_name,
        d.house_name            
FROM    students a
        INNER JOIN students_subjects b
            ON b.student_id = a.id
        INNER JOIN subjects  c
            ON b.subject_id = c.id
        INNER JOIN houses d
            ON a.house_id = d.id
WHERE   b.class_years_section_id = 1 AND 
        b.school_session_id = 1 AND 
        a.is_active = 1
```

Comment: what do you want to know more?

Comment: i am trying to fetch house name from houses table too . but it shows me null

Comment: first, can you explain to me what do you want to do? I see you are joining `students_subjects` from all tables. If there is no student then the value of house is obviously null.

Comment: i have table students where i have fields house_id and another table  named houses having field id, house_name,  and students_subjects table  having field student_id.

Comment: Now i need to get house name too

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26350/discussion-between-jw-and-rashmi)

Answer (score 0):

You've miss placed the `WHERE` clause, try this:

```
SELECT students_subjects.student_id,students.house_id,students_subjects.subject_id,subjects.subject_name,students.rollno,students.first_name, students.last_name 
FROM students_subjects 
     LEFT JOIN students ON students_subjects.student_id=students.id
     LEFT JOIN subjects ON students_subjects.subject_id=subjects.id  
     LEFT JOIN houses ON students.house_id=houses.id
WHERE students_subjects.class_years_section_id=1 
AND students_subjects.school_session_id=1 AND students.is_active=1
```